# What is a great resource for learning about the implementation details of .NET generic collections?

Tags: .net

I'm interested in understanding the underlying implementation details of generic collections in .NET.  What I have in mind are details such as how the collections are stored, how each member of a collection is accessed by the CLR, etc.

For collections that are analogous to traditional data structures, such as LinkedList and Dictionary, I think I have an understanding of what's going on underneath.  However, I'm not as certain about collections like List (how is set up such that it is both indexable and expandable?) and SortedList, so any leads as to what I could look up to learn more about them would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A great way to start looking at the implementation details is opening up [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and decompiling the original source code. You can decompile the source code to C# or VB and also analyze dependencies in the code. A downside is that Reflector isn't able to produce easy to read code from optimized code and enumerators (which are an important part of a collections implementation).

Microsoft has also released the original source code, which does additionally provide all the original comments and unobscured variable names. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx) how to enable it. You'll need to write a small demo program to make Visual Studio download the right sources, but then they'll be cached in some folder so you can easily access them outside the debugger. Another option would be to use some tool that downloads the complete sources. I think there was an MSDN Download with the sources too.

Another thing you might want to have a look at is how generics actually work. They're the basics on which the collections are built. Compared to Java, the .NET implementation is superior because it allows collections of value types without taking a performance hit. I have written a [blog post](http://jorudolph.wordpress.com/2010/04/21/net-generics-implementation/) on this topic, so you might want to check out that or read the [official Microsoft Paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/akenn/generics/designandimplementationofgenerics.pdf) directly.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at Reflector. Using this you can open up any class in the BCL and look at its innards and how it's implemented. Amazing way to learn code.

Otherwise, you can set visual studio to step into .net code in Options Debugging dialog and step into any collection as you are debugging..

Comment: Agreed. Reflector is one of the single most useful tools for me when programming in C#.